# Error during IOS SDK Generate Build using command line?

Tags: ios, command-line, xcode8

I would like to generate a build using command line for my iOS application (instead of Xcode). I have created a sample here: https://kamirana@bitbucket.org/kamirana/mfptest.git
when i try to export the build using command line script it throws following error:
[image]
**Command line script used for Archive and export:**

Archive: `xcodebuild archive -workspace  MFPTest.xcworkspace -scheme MFPTest -archivePath MFPTest.xcarchive`

Export:  `xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath MFPTest.xcarchive -exportPath MFPTest -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist`

Comment: Read the following blog post when the time comes to archive an Xcode project: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/17/prepare-ios-apps-for-app-store-submission/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated IBM Mobile first SDK to the latest version (**IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation (8.0.2017022013)**) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try generating a build using command line tools with latest `Xcode 8` (i.e `8.2.1`) to resolve the above issue.